# Error Composer Rest Server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have follow Hyperledger Composer [here](http://https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial) and all step is done.

But when i restart my PC and try to connect to Hyperledger Composer via command 'composer-rest-server' have error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugXr0.png)

> Discovering types from business network definition ... 
> Connection
>   fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query
>   business network. Error: Connect Failed 
> It will be retried for the
>   next request. 
> Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error
>   trying to query business network. Error: Connect Failed 
> Error:
>   Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network.
>   Error: Connect Failed
>       
> at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/linux-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:713:34)
>       
> at <'anonymous'>

Please help! Thank You.

Comment: Please provide the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data/48075379#48075379) answer for restarting the underlying Fabric before starting the REST Server.

Answer (score 0):

When you restart your system, you also shut down all running docker containers. Restart containers(your blockchain network) before launching composer rest server.