# how start Fabric without losing previous data

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I started playing whith Hyperledger Composer and it's pretty awesome.
for now I'm able to deploy a business network, import the network administrator identity, and generating a REST server.

Now I thought by just running `./startFabric.sh` it' will be possible to start the REST server cause the network is already deployed, but no ,
so I deployed again , import the admin , finally starting the REST server, and..... I lost all the data.

- so what I'm doing wrong ?
- how to start REST server without redeploying the bizNet again ?
- how to keep data available ?

thank you all

**Update**

thank you @r-thatcher

so just to resume:
 - go to  `/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/`
 - copy the "`composer`" folder for ex. in your app folder
 - go to your `app-folder/composer` 
 - `docker-compose start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startFabric.sh script is more of a reset than a start ...

Please see this previous answer [Restart Development Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data)

Comment: thank you that's perfect , I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do that