# Saving data on Hyperledger-Composer network

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I the last weeks I have completed the Principal Hyperledger-Composer tutorials and I have created a private network for testing some features.
I have noticed that if you close your PC or stop the fabric (`./stopFabric`), and restart the private-network, it will be empty. You lose every action you perform in the network using the rest-server (add client, transaction history, etc).

Is there a way for saving my actions? Do I have to use a "multiple-organization-network" (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) for maintaining the status of my data?
I have to maintain always online a peer for not loosing my data?

Comment: This previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data) should explain how to keep the data.

Comment: thank you @James :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read [How to restart the fabric composer without losing the existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data)  - you need locate the correct `docker-compose.yaml` file(s) and (from the directory or providing the path the appropriate command below) preserve them using:

- Run `docker-compose stop` to stop the Fabric Containers
- Run `docker-compose start` to restart where you left off.