# How to keep data while restart hyperledger composer rest server or composer-playground

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've been followed some tutorial such as

1. [Saving data on Hyperledger-Composer network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386500/saving-data-on-hyperledger-composer-network)
2. [How to restart the fabric composer without losing the existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data)

Based on [composer network start error](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/issues/127), I must added one line of code `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` but I've an error and the network can't start normally

```
✖ Starting business network definition.
This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network.
Error: Unable to initalize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was
Error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

Please, tell me what should I do to fix my problem

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was wrong when I write my error message...

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Unable to initalize channel.
Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied:
channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue try below steps may help:

1. Stop all the ENV
2. Remove cards created using command  (composer card delete)
3. Start the ENV again

Comment: can you try to stop ENV and  delete also crypto-config folder and files like composer- genesis.block and composer-channel.tx then start again

Comment: yah, I've tried..
1. I've tried reinstall my businessnetwork. and fail
2. and have tried to re-install my vm-ware, still fail
3. I try to follow some tutorial on internet, still fail

Comment: are you sure that the Env started correctly ? before installing the BNA and starting business network

Comment: how we know that Env has started correctly? All of my application that I create with hyperledger can't store data after I stop or start fabric network.
I've checked , every we restart our network, couchdb will be remove so I follow that tutorial to fix it, but still can't fix my error..