# Composer network start timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to do a composer network start with the following command:

`composer network start --networkName cgi-blockchain --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

It then goes on to;

`Starting business network definition. This may take a while...`

But after a couple of minutes it says;

`Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid response from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed`

Anyone has a clue how to fix? I followed the tutorial on: 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your network is not up.

start with a clean slate I'd say. 
the following commands are all run inside your fabric-dev-servers folder.

do a :

1. *./tearDownFabric.sh* or *./stopFabric.sh* if you want something less destructive
2. *./startFabric.sh*
3. *./createPeerAdminCard.sh*
   this last command might fail if the card is already there. You can check this with *composer card list*

if you need to delete cards you can use this:
*composer card delete --card **name***
you get the **name** from the list command

switch to the folder where your network definition files are and run the usual commands :

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile your-network@0.0.1.bna

composer network start --networkName your-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1

composer card import --file admin@your-network.card

at this point you can start the rest server with 
composer-rest-server

note, you will need to update these commands with your bna name and version, plus password, card names, whatever you have in your setup

if you change the name of the project, then be consistent, change the name of the network card, your namespaces, configuration files everything. wherever you had tutorial-network, replace with the new name, change the name of the bna file as well. Basically make a note of all the commands you used to create the tutorial-network and repeat them changing the name to the new one. I did the same thing with my project and once I got everything right, it wasn't a problem anymore

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer! I have been doing some debugging and narrowed it down to the following i've named my project cgi-blockchain if I change the name to tutorial-network everything starts just fine. You might have any idea why this is?

Comment: added more to deal with the changed name.

Comment: Thanks again I followed all your steps including deleting existing cards and changed the project name to something else and it did seem to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE:" means a network connect failure - so if you are using the standard development fabric, and following the Developer tutorial, I would say that your Fabric is probably not started.

Before you run the startFabric.sh script again - read [this previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data) about starting / stopping the development Fabric.