# Composer network install: ERROR no valid responses from any peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm working on the hyperledger blockchain on Ubuntu 18-04 LTS via this tuto [hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) . I have installed all the pre-requisites and in this step of running "composer network install", I faced this issue and tried some solutions but still not working.
Any help please ? Thanks !

```
~/tutorial-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
```

✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed

[Docker ps and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhxsU.png)

Comment: can you post the output of `docker ps` - What Composer version are you using?

Comment: I added the result of docker ps and version to the question. Thanks for your help !

Comment: based on the output of `docker ps` your fabric network is not running - the answer below. You need to download Fabric docker images and set it up - Step Four of [this page](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) describes how to stand it up, then follow the section "Controlling your dev environment" in that link - to save/ your Fabric environment (if you shutdown your m/c) - see answer 2 here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data

Comment: Thanks to you all ! it works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just mentioning this for others who might face this issue - While in your case fabric network was not running, in my case it was an issue with proxy. Once I cleared that, I was able to deploy successfully.

Comment: how did you dealt with proxy issue ?

Answer (score 5):

your fabric network is not running.

go to your fabric-dev-servers folder and run *./startFabric.sh*

if you get any errors there, like some containers already exist then do a *./teardownFabric.sh* first then run the start command again.

This will give you a basic running network with one org, one peer and one orderer.

Once your network is running then you need to create your admin card by running *./createPeerAdminCard.sh*

only at this point you are ready to install and start your chaincode.