# Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I already searched around for solutions but nothing seems to work in my case.

```
dany@ubuntu:~/Blockchain/tutorial-network$ composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.2 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.2

Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed
```

I already restartet the Factory and restartet Ubuntu but I still get this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer network install: ERROR no valid responses from any peers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185717/composer-network-install-error-no-valid-responses-from-any-peers)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem. Make sure you have right versions of prerequisites installed in your system. In my case, I had wrong docker version installed.

Comment: Thank you. I redone the whole tutorial and reinstalled the prerequisites and then it worked :)