# Hyperledger composer disappears after turning off the PC

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, uninstallation, hyperledger-composer

I follow this guide for installation (on Mac)
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html#appendix

and this one for developing a business network
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/developer-tutorial

everything is fine, unless when I shutdown the computer, the composer seems to be uninstalled!! Mac's terminal does not recognize composer commands and I have to uninstall and install all them again! Can you give your idea about what the cause is? Thanks

Comment: hi, the 2nd link is old and can't be used with the first (correct tutorial is https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial ) - see the table of COMPOSER versions on this wiki page (see 'release stream' -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/wiki) . As for the Fabric side, you need to quiesce/stop the Fabric-related docker containers first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data ..continued ..

Comment: type `which composer` - from the same user with which you installed Composer modules (and which must be a non-root user, and not installed via `sudo`). Unless you reset a virtual machine of course (to lose your current state)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have install all composer package with -g and Not using nvm. If using nvm then make sure to be on same version every time you use composer command.