# Hyperledger Fabric :- Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

While deploying an empty business network , getting below errors :-

[image]

Front end :-

```
An error has occurred
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
```

In the logs :-

```
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
error: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnectionManager     :fabric-client()           [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnectionManager     :fabric-client()           [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
    at checkState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:838:16)
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_validatePeerResponses()  Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :install()                 Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
    at HLFConnection.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:518:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
error: [Hyperledger-Composer] :ConnectorServer          :connectionDeploy()        Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
    at HLFConnection.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:518:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
warn: [Hyperledger-Composer] :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events
```

---

[image]

Still the error is coming even if all the containers are up and running .
When i am exectuing below command :-

```
bcuser@CUSVLDEV1HFB01:~/fabric-dev-servers/tutorial-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
â Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed
```

Comment: formatted code, inlined image

Comment: Is your fabric network running successfully?

Comment: This error is getting generated while deploying business network. How can I check fabric network is running successfully or not ?

Comment: Assuming you are using the standard development Fabric, the standard PeerAdmin card should be looking for the Fabric on 'localhost', so if the Containers are up and running I wonder if you have a networking problem or a firewall active?  Try this curl command to hit the CA container - "curl http://localhost:7054/api/v1/cainfo" you should see a few lines of output starting with the CA name.  If you do not see it, then either your fabric is not running or you have some networking issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot and seeing the cards, it looks like you have connected OK previously and been able to deploy a test Business Network.  So it does look like the Fabric you are trying to connect to is not available (not started?)

Have you restarted the computer where the Fabric is hosted?

On the computer where the Fabric is hosted try the command `docker ps` to see if there are any Dock Containers running.  You can also try `docker ps -a` to see ALL containers whether running or not.

If your Fabric is not running, and you use the 'Development Fabric' provided by the Composer tools, [please see this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data) to understand how the startFabric.sh script works.

Comment: The fabric is running fine but still error is coming