# Can not ping business network after restart

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed the instructions on https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html and https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html. After a restart of the Ubuntu server I started the fabric again and tried to ping the network:

```
cd ~/fabric-dev-servers
export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv12
./startFabric.sh
$ composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: make sure the chaincode tutorial-network has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/tutorial-network responded with error: could not find chaincode with name 'tutorial-network'
Command failed
```

Comment: Your fabric is not preserved if you restart your operating system or if you perform a startFabric.sh call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data for more details

Comment: have you installed tutorial-network on fabric network?

Comment: @MaheshRajput yes, please see my answer below

Comment: @david_k thx, see my answer below

Comment: still you get same error or solve?

Comment: the problem is solved, thx

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @david_k, I also installed and started the network, which works well:

```
$ cd ~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer
$ docker-compose stop
$ docker-compose stop
$ cd ~/tutorial-network
$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
$ composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
$ composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network
$ composer-rest-server
```